# Rails server not starting, because of missing pg gem. Deinstalled postgres, but am getting the same error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am getting the error when trying to start the Rails 5 server.

> Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. 
>   Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum >required by ActiveRecord).

I deleted local postgres via brew, removed also the existing mac app.
This is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.0.0'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I used

> bundle install --without production

But I am still getting the same error. Can anyone help please?

Thanks, 
Zin

Comment: Can you share your database.yml, Did you successfully complete db:migrate?

Comment: haven't started with creating models yet. Trying to start a clean server

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8m_edZ-RcKwdEowdXJfQUIxRE0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: try with simple "bundle install"

Comment: @hardik tried so, now getting the message **ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished No connection pool with id primary found.** Meanwhile I noticed that I am able to start the rails server as root but not as the local user

Comment: Are you sure your RAILS_ENV is development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>It appears to me that you set up your application with the rails command and passed the option to utilize a postgres db.  This will automatically stub out your database.yml file, and configure it for postgres.  To be honest, I suggest you set up a database just like what you'd expect in prod.  It's not that heavy and will save you headaches. (like this!)</s>

While I don't think this is the best thing to reason about, personally, you might try configuring your rails app like this:

**In your Gemfile:**

```
group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  # Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
end
```

**And then in your config/database.yml:**

```
postgres: &postgres
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

sqlite: &sqlite
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *sqlite
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *sqlite
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *postgres
  database: postgresapp_production
  username: postgresapp
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRESAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

This should hopefully work for you.

To explain, all I've done is basically taken the stubbed configuration from a sqlite rails app and pasted the default, development, and test configuration sections from the database.yml file into a postgres rails app's database.yml over top of the development and test sections.  Then I changed all the "default"s in the sqlite configuration to "sqlite" and all the "default"s in the postgres section to "postgres".  Then I added the sqlite gem to the development/test environments in the Gemile and moved the pg gem to production only.

You'd have to run the bundle command and the db:create task before you can run it.

Comment: yeah well, he'll have some headaches while trying to set up postgres locally. Creating db user and giving it proper permissions, for example.

Comment: While I don't disagree that the basic setup and configuration of postgres is going to take some amount of time (and possibly learning), the exercise is a valuable one that is best done in a development or sandbox environment, in my opinion.  Regardless, knowing how to set up postgres is good knowledge for someone who hopes to run a production app on postgres (as his configuration indicates.)  Maintaining a rails project with multiple database types is more trouble than that, I think, too.

Comment: I added a new answer indicating how I think you can do what he's expecting.  Hopefully it helps.

Comment: @chad_  I followed your original comment and used postgres as my dev environment as well and it worked. Will setup another environment tomorrow or so with your second advice. Many thanks Chad

Comment: No problem, at all!  I'm happy to help. Check out [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html) for some justification for just using postgres from the start.  The extensive and more complex data types give you a lot of freedom of expression while modeling data.

Comment: @chad_ meanwhile I used the 2 db variant which you proposed and everything works fine. thanks again, also for the link above